# Is there a way read constant value from fragment shader in cpu side?

Tags: swift, constants, metal, fragment-shader

I am studying with raywenderlich metal by tutorials book. there is an example in the book about selection object. I am new in Metal and I am sorry about my English.

```
typedef struct {
  uint width;
  uint height;
  uint tiling;
  uint lightCount;
  vector_float3 cameraPosition;
  uint objectId;
  uint touchX;
  uint touchY;
} Params;

//this struct sent to fragment shader by
encoder.setFragmentBytes(&params, length: MemoryLayout<Params>.stride, index:
ParamsBuffer.index)

//end hit test in fragment shader like this

fragment float4 fragment_main(constant Params &params [[buffer(ParamsBuffer)]],
//...


  if(params.objectId != 0 && objectID == params.objectId) {
            material.baseColor = float3(0.9, 0.5, 0);
            
        }
```

just I can hit test in fragment shader.. if I want get selected objectId value in swift side
what should I do.. or suppose to be hit test just here.. I didn't understand this part. values can be share CPU and GPU side (in this example **objectId**) or just I have to process values in shader which value I sent. Is somebody can explain me please?

selection test working correctly but..
objectId value always **0** when I try get **objectId** value in swift side

```
print(params.objectId)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way read constant value from fragment shader in cpu side?

Yes, you have to create a new **MTLBuffer** object from the specified data and then binding it to the fragment shader, with the `setFragmentBuffer(_:offset:index:)` method.